# String Contains only alphabetical REGEX

Tags: apex, trigger, regular-expressions

My below code doesn't return true in result:

```
String NameRegex = '/^[A-z]+$/';
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(NameRegex);
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher('TEST');
Boolean result = MyMatcher.matches();
```

result will throw always false. What the problem?

Comment: Documentation says: "A pattern is a compiled representation of a regular expression. Patterns are used by matchers to perform match operations on a character string.", so it is not a reg exp itself. - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm. Try to use [A-z]+, that will work

Comment: @kurunve A pattern is a compiled regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apex Regex isn't like JavaScript's regex. You don't start/end with / characters unless you're trying to match them. For example, given your code, the string `/hello/` would match. Also, `A-z` is not correct, because it would match all characters between `A` and `z`, which, if you look at a character map, includes some punctuation as well (`[\]^_` characters). You need to match `A-Za-z`, because regex is case sensitive.

```
String NameRegex = '^[A-Za-z]+$';
```

This code will match the values you're looking for.

As an alternative, you can also match against \p{Alpha}:

```
String NameRegex = '^\\p{Alpha}+$';
```

Comment: Please could you explain why this doesn't work? Is it also to do with regions?
String candidate = 'A0B1C2bar';
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('bar$');
Boolean b = p.matcher(candidate).matches();
System.debug('b result = '+b);